# How to extract words in order?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to extract the differences when comparing two PDFS. I have attached an image to give a glimpse of the PDFs.
[image: Side-by-side view of PDF1 and PDF2]

I have extracted the line-by-line differences between the two PDfs. I have also extracted word-by-word the differences. But the words are not extracted in correct order. I have used the below code to extract word-by-word.

```
for f, s in zip(changed_lines, deleted_lines):
    if f != s:
        changed_words = set(f.split()) - set(s.split())
```

Here, changed_lines is the lines in PDF1 and not in PDF2. And deleted_lines is the lines present in PDF2 and not in PDF1. In changed_words, thee extracted words are not in order.
Ques: I need to extract the words in the same order as given in PDF.

Comment: Try [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html).

Answer (score 0):

A set is unordered and thus does not keep the order at which it was extracted. Also a set would remove duplicates within the same line.

To keep the same order you'd have to find another approach. One approach would be by iterating the f and s and check similarity by word. Anther could be to one-hot-encode (convert each unique word to a number) and then do vector subtraction between the one-hot-encoded vectors and check if the difference between numbers != 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PDFCompareTrueDiff https://pypi.org/project/PDFCompareTrueDiff/ library for compare two pdf files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. 
Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. 
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).